# Loosening stuck threshold screws

Tags: doors, installation

I built & installed a new exterior door, including a new sweep. The threshold has wide aluminum "screws" for adjusting to the door sweep, however these appear to be frozen in place, all the way down. I tried using my drill clutch (all the way up to 10) and these won't budge. I switched to drill mode, and the bit broke. I have soaked the area in mineral oil but that hasn't seemed to help. Since they are aluminum, they are going to be relatively soft, so I'm hesitant to use something like an impact driver, but that's probably my next move. I thought these adjusters were simply screwed into wood or plastic, not more aluminum. Suggestions? TIA

Comment: This sounds dumb, but have you tried turning them the other way? I have a sneaking suspicion that I've met backwards ones in the past.

Comment: What brand? Are you sure they're adjustable? Believe it or not I've seen those that appeared to be but weren't. That was disappointing.

Comment: And yes, they can be counter-intuitive. Running them _in_ usually lowers the threshold, if I recall correctly.

Comment: If the drill bit broke, they are probably not aluminum, or a very cheap bit.

Comment: Mineral oil is not usually a penetrating oil of choice. Try something that's _designed_ as a penetrating oil like PB Blaster™ or Kroil™. These are designed to seep into the fine gaps in thread and to chemically break down the mechanical bonds of corrosion that have formed. Also, try reversing as suggested above.

Comment: I was able to turn one of them and, as a couple people have pointed out, left/CCW raises the threshold. I got an impact driver, and that got the other ones moving. I got it fixed, thanks all for the comments/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a good driver bit. I can't remember the last time I broke one, but a hammer and a cheater bar were involved. Use an impact driver in both directions.

Comment: Impact driver got the stuck ones going. All set! I got the Craftsman CMMT14014, and the supposedly CV "Flat 8" bit actually bent/twisted a little, but thankfully didn't snap.